# How to avoid creating new columns row as string with double quotes in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

With sequelize I am trying to store a stringify JSON as follows:

```
objectToStore: {
  myColumn: '[{"date":"2020-09-30 14:00:00","offset":-5},{"date":"2020-10-01 22:00:00","offset":-5}]'
}
```

Then when I am looking for the new row into the database, I realize that it has being save with double quotes as follows:

```
"[{\"date\":\"2020-09-30 14:00:00\",\"offset\":-5},{\"date\":\"2020-10-01 22:00:00\",\"offset\":-5}]"
```

BTW I'm using sequelize.model.bulkCreate().

How can I avoid this double quote wrapping in a stringify JSON or a stringify Array ?.

Comment: JSON always uses double quotes for properties and string data. In order to show it inside double quotes you have to escape the internal double quotes

Comment: The thing is I just want to store the string just like that as a string even if it was a stringify JSON without double quotes.